# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string - running .run file

Tags: installation, debian, crunchbang

I am trying to run a `.run` file, I log in as SU and run the following command:

```
sh xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
 Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

What is the cause of this?

Comment: The cause is stated (`Syntax Error`).  Are you more interested in how to fix it?  If so, is it plain text (can you `cat *.run`)?

Comment: The output is just gibberish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is probably an unterminated quoted string in the installer. (well duh!).

Either run it with the -x option to get more debug information, or open the installer in an editor and look for unmatched pairs of quotes.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#My demo installer!
#
echo "starting here!"
echo "and an error in this line
echo "We will never get here!"
```

Notice the missing closing quote (`"`) in the second echo line.

---

Edit:

I just downloaded a file called `xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run` from sourceforge (which I assume is the same file as you are using) and when I opened it in vim I noticed it starts with `^?ELF^`. This file seems to be an ELF binary.

Using the file command on it confirms this:
`file: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped`

It is not a shell script and the normal way to execute it would either be:

1. `xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run` (assuming the directory is in your search path),
2. or with the full path prepended. E.g. `./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run` if you are already in the same directory where the file is. (This is why @erhun's answer worked).

Comment: I'll take a look, I assumed it being a "offical" download that it wouldn't have any errors in it hence why I assumed it was something I'd done wrong.

Comment: The next problem is I can't open the file, either with an editor (inc Vi) or even `cat` the file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It will work with this way.

```
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run  and had the same message.
None of these answers worked for me because I think this is the x64 bit version and I was trying to install it on a 32bit Linux Mint.

Instead I downloaded xampp-linux-1.8.3-2-installer.run (notice the lack of x64 in the file name) and this one worked.
I did the chmod , then sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.3-2-installer.run  and after good few seconds i had the gui installer running.

PS. You'll need to go to sourceforge because apachefriends.org website will give you x64 version as default download.

Answer (score 0):

Looks not a problem with 64-bit OS.

I got same error and 'uname -m' can confirm it (displays x86_64), although I was already sure specifically purchase 64-bit machine.

Looks like while downloading (wget for many hours, very slow mobile Internet), 'xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4-installer.run' got corrupted!